how to compress multi images in Laravel?
I try to compress multi images , I have this code before compress:
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Resources\PhotoResource;
use App\Models\Apartment;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Photo;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
// use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
public function addImages(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = [
            'apartment_id' => 'required|exists:apartments,id',
            'images.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fields);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $msg = $validator->messages()->first();
            return $this->fail($msg);
        }

        $uploadedImages = [];

        $images = $request->file('images');

        if (!is_array($images)) {
            return $this->fail('Images must be an array.');
        }
        $apartmentId = $request->input('apartment_id');

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imageName = 'img_' . rand(1, 150000) . '.png';
            $dir = "images/apartments_images";
            $image->move(public_path($dir), $imageName);
            $path = $dir . '/'
                .
                $imageName;
//            $quitUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' . $path;
            $quitUrl = url($path);

            $data = Photo::create([
                'url' => $quitUrl,
                'apartment_id' => $apartmentId,
            ]);

            $uploadedImages[] = new PhotoResource($data);
        }

        return $this->success($uploadedImages);
    }

and I try to compress multi images by use this line code $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath()); and this line  $img->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) { $constraint->aspectRatio(); })->save(public_path($dir . '/' . $imageName), 75);
in complete script
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Resources\PhotoResource;
use App\Models\Apartment;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Photo;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
// use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function addImages(Request $request)
    {
        $fields = [
            'apartment_id' => 'required|exists:apartments,id',
            'images.*' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $fields);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $msg = $validator->messages()->first();
            return $this->fail($msg);
        }

        $uploadedImages = [];

        $images = $request->file('images');

        if (!is_array($images)) {
            return $this->fail('Images must be an array.');
        }
        $apartmentId = $request->input('apartment_id');

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imageName = 'img_' . rand(1, 150000) . '.png';
            $dir = "images/apartments_images";
            $image->move(public_path($dir), $imageName);
            $path = $dir . '/'
                .
                $imageName;
                $img = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        
                // Compress the image
                $img->resize(800, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                })->save(public_path($dir . '/' . $imageName), 75);
//            $quitUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' . $path;
            $quitUrl = url($path);

            $data = Photo::create([
                'url' => $quitUrl,
                'apartment_id' => $apartmentId,
            ]);

            $uploadedImages[] = new PhotoResource($data);
        }

    return $this->success($uploadedImages);
}

but I got this error : Intervention\Image\Facades\Image not found in file
than I try to Installation the package composer require intervention/image "^2.5" 
and I put this code  'aliases' => [  'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class ],
but I always  got this error :
Error: Class 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' not found in file
and when I put this  'providers' => [  Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,],
I got this error : Class &#039;Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider&#039; not found in file

you can use this code for save and change height abd width image with intervention/image package.
$result = Image::make(image input name)->fit($width, $height)->save(path to save), null, image extension);

